# How to install imapclient

Tags: python, imapclient

I’m trying to use the IMAP client library:

https://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

I download the zip:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/0.13

Next I used windows command prompt and  pip to install:

Ran:  `pip install imapclient`

This placed/created a director in my site-pages directory `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\IMAPClient-0.13-py2.7.egg`

which I can open and find all the files, but I can’t open IDE and import imapclient or run the examples without getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named imapclient
```

Any ideas, what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and below are the steps is used to install imapclient.
 Step1: Clone IMAPClient repository to install it from source.

```
git clone https://github.com/mjs/imapclient.git
```

Step2: Navigate to imapclient folder on your computer. Mine was installed on my home directory on linux so the command i used was:

```
 $ cd imapclient/
```

Step3: Time to install imap using pip while inside the imapclient folder.

```
pip install -e .
```

PS:NOTE THE dot(.) ARGUMENT PASSED ON THE COMMAND.

[Above installation steps in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xreq.png)

[Using your system change directory command, navigate to the cloned imap client folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Het.png)

[pip install and verify on the python interpreter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gplCu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is set properly: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#configuring-python